# (intermediate value).toBigNumber is not a function

Tags: web3js, truffle-contract

My Dapp was working fine, but after I upgraded web3.min.js to the most recent version, I am getting these errors.

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).toBigNumber is not a function
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: TruffleContract is not defined

```
initContract: function() {
    $.getJSON('Pets.json', function(data) {
      App.contracts.RealEstate = TruffleContract(data);
      App.contracts.RealEstate.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
    });
},
```

Seems like the new web3 doesn't recognize some parts in truffle-contract.js or the other way around. Any fix for this?

Comment: Truffle uses web3 v0x, which implements function `web3.toBigNumber`, while the equivalent function implemented in web3 v1x is `web3.utils.toBN`. Moreover, the objects returned from these two functions are different!!! One way to solve your problem is by forcing the old web3 version in your `package.json` file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Now I have to use web3 1.0 because I need to use `create()` function that exists in 1.0 version. If truffle doesn't support 1.0 then should I manually import `abi` from artifact file and use it to instantiate it?

Comment: I am unable to answer your question without seeing actual code (and to be honest, I cannot really understand much from the code that you have posted).

Comment: There's a branch of truffle that support web3 v1.0 https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/next but it is also in beta so it might not work properly.

Comment: You can convert BigNumber to string.

Answer (score 0):

to get around this I had to install old version of web3

```
$ npm i web3@0.20.6
```

Comment: I wouldn't go back to such an old version

Comment: You're right, wouldn't want to use something that old in general, but it's what was required for an outdated tutorial I was doing, so ok in that case